# How to make this code more compact and readable

Tags: python, python-2.x

My below code is working fine but I want to make it more Pythonic. Furthermore, I want to get rid of nested ifs and make the code more compact and readable. Any suggestions? Here project_id and status_change_to are string objects. This code updates the status of certificate.

```
    def execute(self, project_id, cert_obj_json, status_change_to):
        if cert_obj_json != "":
            cert_obj = ssl_certificate.load_from_json(
                json.loads(cert_obj_json)
            )
            cert_details = cert_obj.cert_details

            if status_change_to != "" and status_change_to is not None:
                cert_details['Fastly']['extra_info']['status'] = (
                    status_change_to)
                cert_details['Fastly'] = json.dumps(cert_details['Fastly'])
                self.storage_controller.update_certificate(
                    cert_obj.domain_name,
                    cert_obj.cert_type,
                    cert_obj.flavor_id,
                    cert_details
                )

                service_obj = (
                    self.service_storage.
                    get_service_details_by_domain_name(cert_obj.domain_name)
                )
            # Update provider details
                if service_obj is not None:
                    service_obj.provider_details['Fastly'].\
                        domains_certificate_status.\
                        set_domain_certificate_status(cert_obj.domain_name,
                                                  status_change_to)
                    self.service_storage.update_provider_details(
                        project_id,
                        service_obj.service_id,
                        service_obj.provider_details
                    )
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Can you edit the post to explain what this code is supposed to do? What kinds of object are `project_id`, `cert_obj_json`, `status_change_to` etc?

Comment: @GarethRees project_id is a string of number, status_change_to is a string again and cert_obj_json is a json object..

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please [edit] to add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226)  It appears that this is a fragment of a class definition, but it's not reviewable outside of that context - we can't see what `self` is!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just going through it as I read it:

```
if status_change_to != "" and status_change_to is not None:
```

This seems awfully close to

```
if status_change:
```

so, unless there is some good reason (*good* reason) to write the verbose and repetitive version, you should use the shorter version. Obviously it'll have different behavior when `status_change == 0` for example, but I think we can assume from context that `status_change` is meant to be either a string or (as a special case) `None`.

---

```
service_obj.provider_details['Fastly'].\
    domains_certificate_status.\
    set_domain_certificate_status(cert_obj.domain_name,
                              status_change_to)
```

This is weird indentation, and I prefer not to use backslashes in my own code. So I would write something like

```
fastly = service_obj.provider_details['Fastly']
fastly.domains_certificate_status.set_domain_certificate_status(
    cert_obj.domain_name,
    status_change_to,
)
```

(The comma at the end of each line is just a habit I've formed through long exposure to unclean `git diff` output; presumably it would be harmless to drop the final comma in this case, if you're *sure* there will never be any more arguments added. But then, in software engineering we're always "sure", aren't we...?)

---

```
else:
    pass
```

This is obviously silly.

---

```
if cert_obj_json != "":
```

Same deal as above: if you already know the expected type of the object, and just want to check that it's not-empty, you can use its truthiness. Also, you've got *the entire function body* under this `if`. We can fix that with an early return:

```
    if not cert_obj_json:
        return
```

But actually, I would guess that it would be better to *assert* in this case. Because if `cert_obj_json` is invalid, what is the user doing calling this function at all?

```
    assert cert_obj_json, "I need a JSON object"
```

And then we realize that we could just *remove* the assertion and let `json.loads` fail noisily; the caller will get the same general symptom (an exception) and will have to go fix their buggy code either way. So we've completely eliminated this line of code!

---

```
            )
        # Update provider details
            if service_obj is not None:
```

Your indentation here is wonky.
Which reminds me, for style tips, you should run the whole thing through a linter such as `flake8`. The linter will catch all your weird indentation and such, and even sometimes tell you how to fix it.

---

Putting it all together, we have this:

```
def execute(self, project_id, cert_obj_json, status_change_to):
    cert_obj = ssl_certificate.load_from_json(
        json.loads(cert_obj_json)
    )
    cert_details = cert_obj.cert_details

    if status_change_to:
        cert_details['Fastly']['extra_info']['status'] = status_change_to
        cert_details['Fastly'] = json.dumps(cert_details['Fastly'])
        self.storage_controller.update_certificate(
            cert_obj.domain_name,
            cert_obj.cert_type,
            cert_obj.flavor_id,
            cert_details,
        )

        service_obj = self.service_storage.get_service_details_by_domain_name(
            cert_obj.domain_name
        )
        if service_obj:
            fastly = service_obj.provider_details['Fastly']
            fastly.domains_certificate_status.set_domain_certificate_status(
                cert_obj.domain_name,
                status_change_to,
            )
            self.service_storage.update_provider_details(
                project_id,
                service_obj.service_id,
                service_obj.provider_details,
            )
```

I still have two trickier comments:

- These method names are super long, which is why you're having trouble with line lengths. Do you control them? Could you rename e.g. `self.service_storage.update_provider_details` to `self.storage.set_provider`?
- The line

  ```
  cert_details['Fastly'] = json.dumps(cert_details['Fastly'])
  ```

  is super sketchy, in that it is *mutating*: it's taking the value of the subobject `cert_details['Fastly']` and assigning a new value to it, which of course has an effect on everyone in the program who might be looking at the bigger object `cert_details`. You should try to avoid mutation of this kind in your programs. But in this case I don't see any *easy* fix, so I just mention it, rather than fixing it for you.

---

Oh, and re-reading my cleaned-up code, I see that if `status_change_to` is falsey, then we're just going to load the JSON and then immediately return having done nothing important. So I suspect we could apply the same logic from above: replace the `if` with an early return, then replace the early return with an `assert`, then eliminate the `assert` as redundant.

Result:

```
def execute(self, project_id, cert_obj_json, status_change_to):
    assert cert_obj_json
    assert status_change_to
    cert_obj = ssl_certificate.load_from_json(
        json.loads(cert_obj_json)
    )

    cert_details = cert_obj.cert_details
    cert_details['Fastly']['extra_info']['status'] = status_change_to
    cert_details['Fastly'] = json.dumps(cert_details['Fastly'])

    self.storage_controller.update_certificate(
        cert_obj.domain_name,
        cert_obj.cert_type,
        cert_obj.flavor_id,
        cert_details,
    )

    service_obj = self.service_storage.get_service_details_by_domain_name(
        cert_obj.domain_name
    )
    if service_obj is None:
        return

    fastly = service_obj.provider_details['Fastly']
    fastly.domains_certificate_status.set_domain_certificate_status(
        cert_obj.domain_name,
        status_change_to,
    )
    self.service_storage.update_provider_details(
        project_id,
        service_obj.service_id,
        service_obj.provider_details,
    )
```

For more information on refactorings like this, I highly recommend the book ["The Elements of Programming Style", by Kernighan and Plauger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style).

Comment: thanks for the detailed information..I just didnt get this comment of yours and you havent added this in the final result code of yours:
if cert_obj_json != "":
Same deal as above: if you already know the expected type of the object, and just want to check that it's not-empty, you can use its truthiness. Also, you've got the entire function body under this if. We can fix that with an early return:

     if not cert_obj_json:
        return

Comment: @RamanBalyan An empty string evaluates to `False`, just like a non-empty string evaluates to `True`, when the string is used in a boolean expression. That's why you can replace `if my_string != ""` (which just means my_string is not empty) with `if my_string` (which means my_string is not empty (and also not `None`)).